# R: RMarkdown: Include R File in chunk without evaluating it

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have an R Script that I would like to include in an RMarkdown code chunk *without evaluating it*. The idea is to use the syntax highlighting features that RMarkdown offers in order to publish R-Scripts (with RSConnect) without having to manually copy the content of the script into the chunks.

I had hoped to be able to include the R File as a child, but that doesn't seem to work.

````
```{r child = 'R-File.R',eval=F,echo = T}
```
````

Neither does including it with `read_chunk()`

````
```{r eval=F,echo = T}
knitr::read_chunk("R-File.R")
```
````

Any ideas? The output should be a bunch of `un-evaluated` R-Code with syntax highlighting etc. in the html format via RMarkdown.